# WebBrowser div scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-7, scroll, browser

If I limit WebBrowser's height, and content is longer, scrollbar is created inside the WebBrowser (effectively, HTML page is long), similar to IE in WP7. This scrollbar behaves the way I want to - after swift swipe it continues to scroll, slowing down.

But if I place a div with a scrollbar in the WebBrowser content, this scrollbar behaves like regular HTML scrollbar, it does not keep scrolling after user stops touching the display.

Is there a way to make this work too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not easily. The WP7 IE9 browser control supports the `overflow:scroll` CSS property that allows the user to scroll content within the current page. It is worth noting that most Android and  iPhone browsers do not support this, although it [has been added in iOS5](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5). None of these browser support inertia scrolling for `overflow:scroll`, WP7 included.

The only way to get inertia scrolling for overflow content is to do it yourself using JavaScript. For WebKit browsers there is a popular library, [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll), that provides this functionality. However, it does not work for WP7 (due to lack of CSS3 3D transforms that are used to push the scrolling content onto a different layer for hardware acceleration) - so you will need to write your own implementation. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I started to write such a JS but soon realized that it's not a best approach. I had a partial success, but it's too much with already several other workarounds due to some of the CSS not functioning in WebBrowser ( even though it is functioning in native WP7 browser ).